# Airflow BigQueryOperator DAG doesn't let me query a bigquery-public-dataset: Error: accessDenied

Tags: google-bigquery, cloud, airflow

I have set up an environment in Google Cloud Composer and given the associated service account an Admin role on BigQuery.

My DAG looks something like this:

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {
    'owner': 'My name',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}
gs_bucket = 'europe-central2-my-name-de-4237c541-bucket'

dag = DAG('Test-DAG-Two',
          start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 16),
          schedule_interval='0 8 * * *',
          concurrency=5,
          max_active_runs=1,
          default_args=default_args)

create_test_table_2 = BigQueryOperator(
  task_id='t_create_test_table_2',
  sql=""" SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.blocks` WHERE DATE(timestamp) = "2022-01-19" LIMIT 1000 """,
  destination_dataset_table='myproject.test_data_set.test_table_2${{ ds_nodash }}',
  write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
  bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default',
  google_cloud_storage_conn_id='bigquery_default',
  use_legacy_sql=False,
  dag=dag
)
```

When I run the same DAG but make it so that the SQL query queries one of my own datasets it works as expected. However, when I run this DAG I get this error:

**ERROR - BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {'reason': 'accessDenied', 'message': 'Access Denied: Table bigquery-public-data:crypto_ethereum.blocks: User does not have permission to query table bigquery-public-data:crypto_ethereum.blocks.'}**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now solved. The problem was that the destination_dataset_table is located in the EU but bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.blocks is located in the US. I had to create a new destination dataset located in the US for this to work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).